# PHP Associated Arrays only showing first letter of value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a HTML form with multiple inputs.

I have the below php code to get them inputs and put them in an associated array.

However, when dumping the Associated array the value only shows the first letter...

```
<?php
$valueArray=array
(
  "servername"=>'',
  "serverlocation"=>'',
  "servertype"=>'',
  "serverdescription"=>''
);

 foreach($valueArray as $key => $value)
{
  if (isset($_POST[$key]))
  {
   $postValue = $_POST[$key];
   $actualValue = $postValue;
   $valueArray[$key][$value] = $actualValue;
 }
}

var_dump($valueArray);


?>
```

This is what is dumped -

```
array(4) { ["servername"]=> string(1) "d" ["serverlocation"]=> string(1) "K" ["servertype"]=> string(1) "P" ["serverdescription"]=> string(1) "t" } post
```

How do i get it to store the whole string, and not just the first letter?

Comment: "$valueArray[$key][$value] = $actualValue;" you use the $value, and it is empty according to your array $vlaueArray.

Comment: What exactly is the end result you hope to achieve here?

Comment: So when the user fills in the form, I want to grab the form input names "servername,severlocation" ect, and put what the user has put, inside the associated array, with the correct key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fill the *valueArray* with the content of the POST request you have to do this:

```
$valueArray=array
(
  "servername"=>'',
  "serverlocation"=>'',
  "servertype"=>'',
  "serverdescription"=>''
);

 foreach($valueArray as $key => $value)
{
  if (isset($_POST[$key]))
  {
   $postValue = $_POST[$key];
   $valueArray[$key] = $postValue;
 }
}

var_dump($valueArray);
```

I think you ar wrong with this line:

```
$valueArray[$key][$value] = $actualValue;
```

Comment: You are right, this worked, thank you. I knew it was something stupid, in my mind doing $valueArray[$key] = $whatever  would overwrite the name of the key...but obviously that's not how it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$valueArray=array
(
  "servername"=>'',
  "serverlocation"=>'',
  "servertype"=>'',
  "serverdescription"=>''
);
$postData=array
(
  "servername"=>'serverName',
  "serverlocation"=>'serverLocation',
  "servertype"=>'serverType',
  "serverdescription"=>'serverDescription'
);
 foreach($valueArray as $key => $value)
{
  if (isset($postData[$key]))
  {
   $postValue = $postData[$key];
   $actualValue = $postValue;
   $valueArray[$key] = $actualValue;
 }
}

var_dump($valueArray);
```

Comment: Why should he try this? Don't just post code, explain what he's doing wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: @Barmar He should try this because it works. There is nothing to explain. 
A sentient being will figure out the problem by comparing his code with the example one. In general, these kinds of questions get an instant downvote because of the simplicity of the question. Going into useless detail when explaining the absolute basics of a variable assignment is not necessary.

Comment: If you're going to bother posting an answer, it should be an educational answer.

Comment: If he understood things well enough to make sense of the answer, he wouldn't have made the error in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar Why not? I often make simple silly mistakes that I myself don't see right away, but someone else can see the error right away. I don't need a complex explanation to get the point...seeing a working example is enough in such simple cases. You can see from the accepted answer that no explanation was needed, he got the point.